# Cross reference with from enumerate in section x

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio

everyone. I would like to have a reference like `#section.label_from_enumarete`, but I can't find any option in the reference manual.

For instance I've just put a `\label{sec: text1}` aside the section (or subsection), but it makes me a "double" cross reference.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}   % per disegnare i curcuiti
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}   % per "delimitare" una porzione in cui la mia immagina non può andare
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{enumerate} % per avere nomenclatura romana nell "{enumerate}"
\usepackage{enumitem} % per avere le lettere nell "{enumerate}"

\begin{document}

\section{Preparazione}  \label{sec: prep1}

    I compiti di preparazione per questo laboratorio, sono, dato il seguente circuito (fig. \ref{fig:Cirq_15.1});

        \begin{figure} [H]
            \centering
            \begin{circuitikz}

                %%******************
                % primo OPAMP
                \draw
                (4,1.5) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
                (opamp.+) %node[left] {$v_+$}
                (opamp.-) %node[left] {$v_-$}
                (opamp.out) %-- node[right] {$v_o$}
                (opamp.up) --++(0,0.3) node[vcc]{\textcolor{black}{$V_{cc}$}}
                (opamp.down) --++(0,-0.3) node[vee]{$V_{dd}$};

                %entrata invertente
                \draw               
                (2,4.25) to[R=$R_1$, -- ]  (4.5,4.25) -- (5.25,4.25)
                (5.25,4.25) to [short, -*]  (5.25,1.5)
                (5,1.5) to [short, -o]  (6.75,1.5)
                (2,2) to[short, -- ]  (3,2)
                (2,2) to[short, *-] (2,4.25)
                %               (-1,2) to[C, l=\mbox{$C = 4,7\ nF$}, -- ] (0,2)
                (0,2) to [R=$R_1$, --]  (2,2)
                ;

                %entrata non invertente
                \draw
                (2,1) to[short, -- ]  (3,1)
                (5.25,1.5) to [vR=$R_2$, --] (5.25,-0.5) -- (5.25,-1) -- (2,-1) -- (2,1)                    
                (2,-1) to [C=$C$, *-*] (2,-3)
                (3.75,-1) to[L=$L$, *-*] (3.75,-3)
                (0,2) -- (0,-3) to [short, -o] (6.75,-3)
                ;

                \draw [dashed]
                (5.25,-1) to [R=$R_p$, *-*] (5.25,-3);


                % Sonda 2 + digilent                
                \draw [color=orange] 
                (6.75,-3) to [open ,v_<=$\,U_{out}$] (6.75,1.5);
            \end{circuitikz}
            \caption{Circuito esperienza}
            \label{fig:Cirq_15.1}
        \end{figure}

        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
            \item \label{2a} Ridisegnare il circuito di figura \ref{fig:Cirq_15.1} per vedere chiaramente i due circuiti parziali $\underline{F}(\omega)$ e $\underline{G}(\omega)$ come nell’esempio di figura 13.2 del testo dell'esperienza.

            \item \label{2b} Descrivere matematicamente le funzioni di trasferimento dei due circuiti $\underline{F}(\omega)$ e $\underline{G}(\omega)$ .

            \item \label{2c} Determinare la condizione di oscillazione in funzione di $\omega$ e dei componenti del circuito.

            \item \label{2d} Dalla condizione di oscillazione trovare $\omega$ (e la $f$ di oscillazione) e il valore di R2.
        \end{enumerate}

    \subsection{Punto \ref{sec: prep1}\ref{2a}}

        Per ridisegnare secondo lo schema che espliciti chiaramente la funzione $\underline{F}(\omega)$ e $\underline{G}(\omega)$, bisogna peocedere come segue.


    \FloatBarrier   
    \subsection{Punto \ref{sec: prep1}\ref{2b}} 


    \FloatBarrier
    \subsection{Punto \ref{sec: prep1}\ref{2c}}


    \FloatBarrier
    \subsection{Punto \ref{sec: prep1}\ref{2d}}

  \end{document}
```

And all I'm looking for is an opotions so that my `\subsection{Punto \ref{SoMeThInG} }`, give me only **ONE** link (red box, in the followin figure).

[image]

Giving me the correct number of section and the label from an `enumerate` environement, so in my document there will be only **ONE** label(or reference) showing me `a)`.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. As of now, there's a lot of guess-work required regarding which packages should be loaded.

Comment: Ohhhh..... Sorry, I havent checked it when I've pasted....

Comment: After changing the document class from `standalone` to `article` and making sure that the `hyperref` package gets loaded last rather than first, I still get warning messages such as `Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '-'.`. Please fix these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % per avere le lettere nell "{enumerate}"
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Preparazione}  \label{sec: prep1}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),ref=\thesection\alph*)]
        \item  Ridisegnare il circuito di figura\label{2a}

        \item  Descrivere matematicamente le funzioni di trasferimento dei due circuiti $\underline{F}(\omega)$ e $\underline{G}(\omega)$\label{2b}

        \item Determinare la condizione di oscillazione in funzione di $\omega$ e dei componenti del circuito. \label{2c}

        \item  Dalla condizione di oscillazione trovare $\omega$ (e la $f$ di oscillazione) e il valore di R2.\label{2d}
    \end{enumerate}

\subsection{Punto \ref{2a}}

\subsection{Punto \ref{2b}}

\subsection{Punto \ref{2c}}

\subsection{Punto \ref{2d}}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

where the links direct to the individual enumerate items, not the section title.

Comment: Yeah!!
Exactly like that!!

Comment: I've seen there are some option in referencing: `sec:`, `fig:`, and so on, but in the case of an  alpfabetic `enumerate` inside an `enumerate`, which option for crossreferencing is most suitable ??